# pig-avro: how to customize the way, the avrostorage loads a file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I have a requirement in which we need to customize the way we load a file in pig using avrostorage:

For example, i have an avro file with the following schema:

```
{"namespace": "avroColorCount",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User2",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "content", "type" :  "bytes" }
 ]
}
```

Now if i use the below command its working fine:

```
x = load 'sample.avro' USING AvroStorage() AS (name: chararray, content: bytearray);
```

But, if i want only the 'content'(second column) to be loaded, how can i do that?

If i give,

```
x = load 'sample.avro' USING AvroStorage() AS (content: bytearray);
```

it gives me error:

```
ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is "content:bytearray", right is "name: chararray, content: bytearray"
```

I know this can be done by FILTER.

But our requirement is to get the second column alone in a single step.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code solved it..

```
x = LOAD 'sample.avro' USING AvroStorage('{"type":"record","name":"User2","fields":[{"name":"content","type":"bytearray"}]}');
```